# Jasper Reports - How can sub categories OR groups can be generated in a report?

Tags: jasper-reports

**Table**:

```
| DOCID | TITLE | MAIN_CATEGORY | SUB_CATEGORY |
------------------------------------------------
|     1 |  DOC1 |            M1 |           S1 |
|     2 |  DOC2 |            M1 |           S2 |
|     3 |  DOC3 |            M2 |           S2 |
|     4 |  DOC4 |            M2 |           S1 |
```

**Required Report Format**

**Documents Report**

Category - **M1**

```
| DOCID | TITLE | SUB_CATEGORY |
--------------------------------
|     1 |  DOC1 |           S1 |
|     2 |  DOC2 |           S2 |
```

Category - **M2**

```
| DOCID | TITLE | SUB_CATEGORY |
--------------------------------
|     3 |  DOC3 |           S2 |
|     4 |  DOC4 |           S1 |
```

### Question

What element should i use to get the required output ? and How ? 
Any tutorials ?

Comment: You can read [JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding "Add Report Group".

Steps to achieve this:-

1:- Create a new report.

2:- Add Query

```
   SELECT * 
   FROM table
   ORDER BY MAIN_CATEGORY
```

3:-Go to "Report inspector" in iReport and add "Add Report Group"

```
  a:- Report Group name- category(It can be anything)

  b:- Group by following object:- MAIN_CATEGORY
```

4:- Drag a static text field under category group and name it "Category" and then drag a text field next to this static field and change text field expression to $F{MAIN_CATEGORY}

5:- Drag text filed for "DOCID", "TITLE" and "SUB_CATEGORY" in detail field.